# What's the easiest way to remove <fieldset> border lines?

Tags: html, css

What's the easiest way to remove the **border** lines of a `<fieldset>`?

I mean a cross-browser solution... is that possible ?

Comment: The `<fieldset>` is a really weird tag, and while you can probably get rid of the border, things get weird if you try to do too many other things ...

Comment: ^^ Such as positioning the `<legend>` element. Ew.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

```
fieldset {
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
fieldset {
   border:0 none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*(In regards to [Marko's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4230381/8221877) comment)*

As far as positioning/styling the `<legend>`, I hide the `<legend>` (still put one in there just to be semantic), and position/style an `<h2>` instead.  I find this setup gives me nice styling options for my fieldsets.

- JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/axYQs/

```css
fieldset {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial;
}
legend {
    display: none;
}
h2 {
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
p {
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Enter Name</legend>
    <h2>Enter Name</h2>
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="name"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Hiding the legend will cause accessibility problems because the assistive technology will not read out the legend. The answer with the fieldset border property is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick easy effective way to style it..

assign a class or id to the fieldset element then style it in css.

```
<fieldset class="fieldset">
```

or

```
<fieldset id="fieldset">
css.fieldset {
border: none;
}
```

or

```
fieldset {
border: none;
}
```